# How to predict time feature in time series?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I want to predict next time in time series by deploying deep learning model. I used keras Embedding layer and convert time to vectors  in this way:

```
hours_input=Input(shape=(1,),name='hours_input')
hours_embedding=Embedding(24,64)(hours_input)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs = hours_input, outputs = hours_embedding)
w1=model.layers[1].get_weights()
minutes_input=Input(shape=(1,),name='minutes_input')
minutes_embedding=Embedding(60,64)(minutes_input)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs = minutes_input, outputs = minutes_embedding)
w2=model.layers[1].get_weights()
```

Then I used this vectors as an input of a lstm model. For out put I used one-hot embedding of time and I used categorical cross entropy loss. But my network couldn't be trained. Can someone help me what is wrong with this?

Comment: I've never seen something like this. Are you looking for a way to prepare a dataset for an LSTM network? Are you trying to predict a continuous value? Feel free to provide a toy example.

Comment: @NicolasGervais You know I have some data including some item and the time of occuring them. I want to predict the next time in which the next item occuring .  Do you think my prepration which is embedding time to vectors by using Embedding keras layer is wrong?

Comment: @azin `Embedding` is for text-input. Please provide a reproducible example, including some sample data, expected output, and more clearly specify what you mean by "couldn't be trained".

Comment: @runDOSrun Embedding is for numerical data. I had data that contains hour and minutes. I embedded minutes and hours and then combined them and feed into network. But the network accuracy does not changed.

Comment: Embeddings is typically for word embeddings. If you research a bit, you'll see that they are used to encode semantic, contextual relationships. Again, maybe you can provide a concrete example?

Comment: @runDOSrun I have a dataset one column includes some text data and one column includes date time 2018-06-12 09:55:22. I want to use both of these columns to predict the next time and next item which might be occuured. I don't know how to use time as an input of a neural network. How can I predict time? Is it possibe